# How can I check whether array of objects is empty or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("ListCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.error = false;
        $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + $scope.search + '&r=json')
               .then(function (res) {
                    var titles = [];
                    angular.forEach(res.data.Search, function(item){
                       $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + item.Title + '&y=&plot=full&r=json').then(function(res){
                       if (res.data.Poster === "N/A") {
                         res.data.Poster = "http://placehold.it/350x450/FF6F59/FFFFFF&text=Image+not+Available!!";
                       }
                        titles.push(res.data); 
                      });  
                    });

                   $scope.movie = titles;
                   $scope.results = true;
                   $scope.error = false;
                   $scope.loading = false;


                   if (titles.length==0) {           // not working
                       $scope.results = false;
                       $scope.error = true;
                   }


               })
```

I have been tried several things like :

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(titles).length === 0) 
obj == null
```

None of them seems to work...

Comment: any working sample??

Comment: Can you debug and check if the length is really zero!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http.get()` is async so the statement `if (titles.length==0) {` gets executed right away.

Have a counter to determine when all the Promises get resolved and then perform the check. Move the if statement inside the callback.

```
 var count = res.data.Search.length;

 angular.forEach(res.data.Search, function(item){
   $http.get('http://www.o....rest of code').then(function(res) {
      // rest of code

      titles.push(res.data); 
      if (!count-- && !titles.length) {
          $scope.results = false;
          $scope.error = true;
        }
      }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of **incorrect scope**:

`var titles = [];` is defined inside the `.then`

and you are checking the length outside of `.then`

since `titles` is not available outside `.then` it would not work. (`undefined.length==0`)

**Solution:**

```
.then(function (res) {
                    var titles = [];
                    angular.forEach(res.data.Search, function(item){
                       $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + item.Title + '&y=&plot=full&r=json').then(function(res){
                       if (res.data.Poster === "N/A") {
                         res.data.Poster = "http://placehold.it/350x450/FF6F59/FFFFFF&text=Image+not+Available!!";
                       }
                        titles.push(res.data); 
                      }); 
               $scope.movie = titles;
               $scope.results = true;
               $scope.error = false;
               $scope.loading = false;


               if (titles.length==0) {           // now this will work
                   $scope.results = false;
                   $scope.error = true;
               }  
    });//titles will not be available after this.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the check

```
titles.length
```

will be executed before the

```
titles.push
```

because you use an asynchronous request which will return later.
You need to wrap your statements into the answer-block of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside, but beneficial for my practice and your future help:

Part of the problem you were having was scope-management (JS-scope, not Angular $scope), part of it was concurrency-management, and part of it appeared to be plain old scope-formatting making it hard to see where all control blocks start and end (that gets miserable when it's not just if/else, but with callbacks/promises, too).

This is a small example of how you might consider tackling these problems, through a quick refactor of your issues:

```js
function pluck (key) {
  return function pluckFrom(obj) { return obj[key]; };
}

angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

angular.moule("app").service("omdbService", ["$http", function ($http) {
  function getSearch (search) {
    var searching = $http.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + search + "&r=json")
      .then(pluck("data"));
    return searching;
  }

  function getMovie (title) {
    var searching = $http.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + title + "&y=&plot=full&r=json")
      .then(pluck("data"));
    return searching;
  }

  return {
    getSearch: getSearch,
    getMovie: getMovie,
    getPlaceholderPoster: function () { return "http://placehold.it/350x450/FF6F59/FFFFFF&text=Image+not+Available!!"; }
  };
}]);



angular.moule("app").controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope", "$q", "omdbService", function ($scope, $q, omdb) {
  function loadMovie (movie) {
    return omdb.getMovie(movie.Title)["catch"](function () { return undefined; });
  }
  function movieExists (movie) { return !!movie; }
  function updatePoster (movie) {
    movie.Poster = movie.Poster || omdb.getPlaceholderPoster();
    return movie;
  }
  function setResults (movies) {
    $scope.movie = movies; // $scope.movies, instead?
    $scope.results = true;
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.loading = false;
  }

  function handleError () {
    $scope.results = false;
    $scope.error = true;
  }

  $scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.error = false;

    omdb.getSearch($scope.search)
      .then(pluck("Search"))
      .then(function (movies) { return $q.all(movies.map(loadMovie)); })
      .then(function (movies) { return movies.filter(movieExists).map(updatePoster); })
      .then(setResults, handleError);
  };

}]);
```

There are 8000 valid ways of handling this, and everyone will see it a little differently.
This is also not really how I'd tackle it in production, but not too far off...

Moving all endpoint-calls out to a service which is responsible for those means that any controller in your system (with that module as a dependency) can access them.

Doing small things per function and letting Array.prototype methods do the iterating (IE8 can be shimmed if needed) means that each function is super-specific.

By wrapping the controller/service functions in arrays, and naming their dependencies, they're now minification friendly.

The body of `submit()` is less than 10 lines, and deals with all kinds of crazy async stuff, but I know that I've handled errors like one of the movies returning a 404 (my code should still fire, with the remaining movies, the code of others might not -- most code would either never trigger success or would fail all the way through the program, if the server threw an error for a movie).
Now, I'm not checking that the server is sending the right kind of data for a "movie", but that's different.

Comment: I tried your code as it is. This is intialising everything in my code at the beginning only, like error notif, loading notif etc. If you want I can post the repo link for you to contribute.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look, over the next few days, and potentially submit a PR after that.